# SQL Query result to a variable

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm experiencing issues when trying to get an SQL Query result to a variable:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

```vb
'Connection Data.
Dim LoginData As String = "User ID=User;Password=Password;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Data Source=SQLServer"

'Connection Object.
Dim ConnectionObject As New SqlConnection(LoginData)
ConnectionObject.Open()

'Query.
Dim Query As New SqlCommand
Dim Reader As SqlDataReader
Dim Result As String

Query.CommandText = "SELECT PI_PatternVersion FROM dbo.tb_SystemPatternList WHERE PI_PatternType = 4"
Query.Connection = ConnectionObject
Reader= QuerySmartScan.ExecuteReader()
Result= Reader.Item("PI_PatternVersion")

MsgBox(Result)
```

Comment: the reader needs to `Read` before you try to access the data

Comment: Isn't the ExecuteReader when it reads?

Comment: No, `ExecuteReader` creates the reader object for you

Comment: You might have another problem -  `Query` is a DbCommand object and it gets the SQL, but then you create the reader from `QuerySmartScan` which comes out of nowhere in the code.  Option Strict On would help

Comment: Thanks, managed to get it working by changing the origin of the reader and making it read before accessing the data.
Thanks for the help.